# Convert JSON file into multiple class objects in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, class, object

I'm trying to make a program in C# that allows me to edit level data in JSON:

```json
{
    "ambienceSettings": {
        "fogDDensity": 0.57235307,
        "skyHorizonColor": {
            "a": 1.0,
            "b": 0.010186112,
            "r": 0.12088394
        },
        "skyZenithColor": {
            "a": 1.0
        },
        "sunAltitude": 45.0,
        "sunAzimuth": 315.0
    },
    "complexity": 127,
    "formatVersion": 6,
    "levelNodes": [
        {
            "isLocked": true,
            "levelNodeStatic": {
                "material": "LAVA",
                "position": {
                    "x": 709.82574,
                    "y": 2778.5,
                    "z": 613.0453
                },
                "rotation": {
                    "w": 0.8660254,
                    "y": 0.5
                },
                "scale": {
                    "x": 3084.0,
                    "y": 108.0,
                    "z": 4136.5
                },
                "shape": "CUBE"
            }
        },
        {
            "levelNodeStatic": {
                "color": {
                    "a": 1.0,
                    "r": 0.5
                },
                "material": "DEFAULT_COLORED",
                "position": {
                    "x": 464.0625,
                    "y": 2832.7517,
                    "z": 509.81253
                },
                "rotation": {
                    "w": -4.371139e-08,
                    "y": -1.0
                },
                "scale": {
                    "x": 2.874939,
                    "y": 0.4958496,
                    "z": 2.875
                },
                "shape": "CUBE"
            }
        },
        {
            "levelNodeStart": {
                "position": {
                    "x": 464.125,
                    "y": 2833.0,
                    "z": 510.8751
                },
                "radius": 0.22492802,
                "rotation": {
                    "w": 1.0,
                    "y": -2.0861619e-07
                },
```

I have created classes for each attribute and want to convert every attribute in the JSON file into their respective class objects:

```cs
public class AmbienceSettings
    {
        [JsonProperty("fogDDensity")]
        public double FogDDensity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("skyHorizonColor")]
        public SkyHorizonColor SkyHorizonColor { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("skyZenithColor")]
        public SkyZenithColor SkyZenithColor { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sunAltitude")]
        public double SunAltitude { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sunAzimuth")]
        public double SunAzimuth { get; set; }
    }

    public class Color
    {
        [JsonProperty("a")]
        public double A { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("r")]
        public double R { get; set; }
    }

    public class LevelNode
    {
        [JsonProperty("isLocked")]
        public bool IsLocked { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("levelNodeStatic")]
        public LevelNodeStatic LevelNodeStatic { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("levelNodeStart")]
        public LevelNodeStart LevelNodeStart { get; set; }
    }

    public class LevelNodeStart
    {
        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public Position Position { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("radius")]
        public double Radius { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rotation")]
        public Rotation Rotation { get; set; }
    }

    public class LevelNodeStatic
    {
        [JsonProperty("material")]
        public string Material { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public Position Position { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rotation")]
        public Rotation Rotation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("scale")]
        public Scale Scale { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("shape")]
        public string Shape { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("color")]
        public Color Color { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        [JsonProperty("x")]
        public double X { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("y")]
        public double Y { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("z")]
        public double Z { get; set; }
    }

    public class Level
    {
        [JsonProperty("ambienceSettings")]
        public AmbienceSettings AmbienceSettings { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("complexity")]
        public int Complexity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("formatVersion")]
        public int FormatVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("levelNodes")]
        public List<LevelNode> LevelNodes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("maxCheckpointCount")]
        public int MaxCheckpointCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rotation
    {
        [JsonProperty("w")]
        public double W { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("y")]
        public double Y { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("x")]
        public double? X { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("z")]
        public double? Z { get; set; }
    }

    public class Scale
    {
        [JsonProperty("x")]
        public double X { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("y")]
        public double Y { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("z")]
        public double Z { get; set; }
    }

    public class SkyHorizonColor
    {
        [JsonProperty("a")]
        public double A { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("b")]
        public double B { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("r")]
        public double R { get; set; }
    }

    public class SkyZenithColor
    {
        [JsonProperty("a")]
        public double A { get; set; }
    }
```

I have been attempting for about 2 hours to achieve this and have gotten absolutely nowhere. Hopefully I explained well enough for people to understand and help.

Comment: I can see only the classes , but I need to see the code you were trying and the error you  got.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the root class (Data for example)

```
    Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("ambienceSettings")]
        public AmbienceSettings AmbienceSettings { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("complexity")]
        public long Complexity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("formatVersion")]
        public long FormatVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("levelNodes")]
        public List<LevelNode> LevelNodes { get; set; }
    }
```